# Detailed derivations about Mode Coupling Theory (MCT)

Tags: statistical-mechanics, non-equilibrium, glass

I am currently reading two articles related to mode coupling theory (MCT) and I am stuck in evaluating some ensemble averages, since there is no detailed derivations given. Moreover, the two references I am reading shows different results, which is really confusing.

The (canonical) ensemble average I want to compute is the lower left matrix element of the correlation matrix, $C(t)$, which is defined as

$$\left<j(\mathbf{-q},0)\rho(\mathbf{q},t)\right> = \frac{N}{i}\frac{dF(q,t)}{dt}\text{ where }j(\mathbf{q},t)=i\sum_{i}(\mathbf{q}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}}_{i})e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}_{i}}$$
in reference [1] and
$$\left<j^{L}(\mathbf{-q},0)\rho(\mathbf{q},t)\right> = \frac{N}{iq}\frac{d^{2}F(q,t)}{dt^{2}}\text{ where }j^{L}(\mathbf{q},t)=\sum_{i}(\hat{\mathbf{q}}\cdot\dot{\mathbf{r}}_{i})e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}_{i}}$$
in reference [2]. In both cases, the intermediate scattering function is
$$F(q,t) = \frac{1}{N}\left<\rho(-\mathbf{q},0)\rho(\mathbf{q},t)\right>\text{ where }\rho(\mathbf{q},t)=\sum_{i}e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}_{i}}$$
My question is:

1. I am not sure which equation is right. Are these two equations both right? Since the definition of current $j$ is slightly different, I could expect slightly different results, but number of differentiations are different here...
2. Besides that, I could not derive the formula for the matrix element (I am new to this field). I want to find detailed derivation.

Thanks in advance. These are references I mentioned above.

[1] *Mode-Coupling Theory of the Glass Transition: A primer* by Liesbeth M. C. Janssen (*Front. Phys.* **2018**, 6:97)
[2] *Mode-coupling theory* by David R. Reichman and Patrick Charbonneau (*J. Stat. Mech.* **2005** P05013)

Comment: Yes second proposition 2 is wrong (even from a dimensional analysis point of view. In any case I could not find it from the reference you linked). The first one is right though. If your replace $\rho$ in $F$ by its expression with the exponential and derive it, the result immediately follows (you may have to assume time invariance to get back its exact result).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. What does "you may have to assume time invariance" mean in your answer? I couldn't get it. (By the way, the *wrong* relationship is given between equations (31) and (32) in the reference [2]!)